# ruby mechanize find and fill input tag value

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I need to fill the value of an input tag not surrounded by a form tag, I do not need to submit it, just fill in a value.

I have the code below:

```
  input = my_page.at("#crn_id1")

  my_page.form_with(:id => 'crn_id1').value = '90098'

  input = agent.click(my_page.at('[@value="Submit Changes"]'))

  puts input.content
```

I am getting an error but what I am trying to do is fill out the input tag which has html of:

```
<TD style=padding:10px; CLASS="dedefault"><p class="centeraligntext"></p>
<LABEL for=crn_id1><SPAN class="fieldlabeltextinvisible">CRN</SPAN></LABEL>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="CRN_IN" SIZE="8" MAXLENGTH="5" ID="crn_id1">
</TD>
```

I just want to fill out the input tag which in NO way is surrounded by a form tag with a value of 09987.  I have the correct html page but cant seem to set the value of the input and tag to set it and set it in mechanize.

Comment: Without a form tag the input is useless. Whatever you're trying to do it won't work.

Comment: Try using the watir gem to fill the form. http://watir.com/